# Making a form_tag specific for each user when running each do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a feedback form where each student can list 2 interests.

However, with my code below, it only recognizes interest_1 and interest_2 for the last student and maps the values to all students, instead of a different value for each student. Anyone can shed some light on how to make interest_1 and interest_2 specific for each student?

```
<%= form_tag feedback_send_path, :method => 'post' do %>
  <% @course.students.each do |student| %>
    <%= avatar_for(student, :photo_size => :thumb_small, :class => 'notBig', :size => '50x50') %>
    <%= link_to student.name, user_path(student.id), :class => "profile-link" %>
    <%= text_area_tag 'interest_1', '', :class => 'feedback-form', :placeholder => "Wants to teach..." %>
    <%= text_area_tag 'interest_2', '', :class => 'feedback-form', :placeholder => "Wants to learn..." %>
  <% end %>
<%= submit_tag "Submit", :class => "send-message-button" %>
<% end %>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<%= text_area_tag 'interest_1', '', :class => 'feedback-form', :placeholder => "Wants to teach..." %>
    <%= text_area_tag 'interest_2', '', :class => 'feedback-form', :placeholder => "Wants to learn..." %>
```

Use

```
<%= text_area_tag 'interest_1[]', '', :class => 'feedback-form', :placeholder => "Wants to teach..." %>
    <%= text_area_tag 'interest_2[]', '', :class => 'feedback-form', :placeholder => "Wants to learn..." %>
```

Then have a look at your `params` Hash!

Comment: Now it gives me all the values for each of the users, like User 1 is interested in [Interest 1 for User 1, Interest 2 for User 1, Interest 1 for User 2, Interest 2 for User 2, Interest 1 for User 3, Interest 2 for User 3], as opposed to one line per user.

Comment: yeah so there are any open questions?